# Edit .gitconfig in Cloud9 IDE globally

Tags: git, unix, ubuntu, cloud9-ide

A basic googling didn't yield many good results. If you are in a typical workspace, and open a terminal tab you can easily navigate back one directory and find the `.gitconfig` file.

The problem is, anything you do in there doesn't seem to persist to other workspaces; it only works for that local workspace.

Is there a way to set up configurations for Git globally?

Comment: Still not finding a solution to this issue. I suppose since each workspace runs in its own VM it might not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Cloud9 workspace is like a completely new Ubuntu machine and is self-contained. Any changes you make in one would not affect your other workspaces. The changes made to git would be global within that workspace, and will impact any and all git repositories created within, but not repositories from other workspaces.

It's like any changes you make to one of your laptops will not impact your other laptops, similar is the case for Cloud9 workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set globally as per documentation [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)?  ("**git config --global** ...")
As stated in the documentation "You may see keys more than once, because Git reads the same key from different files. In this case, Git uses the last value for each unique key it sees"

Comment: yes, this what i've done. I've more specifically opened the .gitconfig file in the ubuntu home directory, but that does the same thing as setting properties one by one. If i do a git config --global --list in my other workspaces the lists are different. I guess 'global' is relative within the c9 ide

Answer (score 0):

Create a new workspace and set up git the way you like it using **git config --global** . Also set up the rest of the environment the way you like to work.

Thereafter, to spin-up a new C9 workspace **clone** the one with your preferred environment. The new workspace will have your preferred settings.

If you change the settings after cloning these changes will not propagate across work spaces. But at least it is more convenient than setting up git configurations from scratch with each new workspace.